# Python - request.get() returns 200 - however the information stored on HTML differs from what browser shows. Trying to scrape html. Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

When I ping (request.get()) the website it sends back a 200 code. However, the contents/text differs from what is displayed on browser.

```
import requests

header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
html= 'https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/bd6ceb38-fd5a-493d-afbb-d8e28a6860c4?offset=0&count=200'

html_text = requests.get(html, headers =header).text

print(html_text)
```

Output summary (lot of text but message as follows and doesn't display the same information as on browser):

```
Yahoo works best with the latest versions of the browsers. You're using an outdated or unsupported browser and some Yahoo features may not work properly. Please update your browser version now.
```

Is it my header that is wrong? Or am I missing additional inputs to my request.get()? I've tried browsing for answers and other options without success. Managed to draw from other pages on Yahoo finance with similar logic as below, it seems to be related to the specific html even though this html works perfectly fine in chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your header is fine as it is the newest one. You can use the browser tools to check what is wrong with your request.

If I open your URL I get the status code `302 Redirect Found`. This redirect is automatically used and a new request is sent to the redirect URL. In this case that is the login page, which returns status code `200 Ok`.

Now if we inspect the login page, we can find the output you posted about browser versions. It can be found in the HTML but is not shown on the website. It is a placeholder and is only shown if the user has an old browser.

Picture highlighting the HTML part in question, which is not displayed on the website:

[image]

To summarize, I think what you want is that you are not redirected. It is probably caused by not being logged in. Most websites use additional headers for authorization, which is missing in your case.